# HTTP basic authentication and Spring security: custom failure response

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-security, basic-authentication

I'm trying to implement a Rest web service with Jersey, Spring and Spring security (3.2.5).

I want the server to require the basic auth header for the request to the rest web service. If authentication succeeds, then jersey should handle the request. If it fails, I want to return an empty response with the status 403.

Currently my configuration is the following:

```
<bean id="myAuthenticationEntryPoint"
    class="de.tuberlin.snet.baroudeur.Authentication.EntryPoint" />

<!-- HTTP basic authentication in Spring Security -->
<security:http create-session="stateless" auto-config="false"
        disable-url-rewriting="true" entry-point-ref="myAuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="**" access="ROLE_USER" />
    <security:http-basic />
</security:http>

<security:authentication-manager>
    <security:authentication-provider>
        <security:user-service>
            <security:user name="username" password="password"
                authorities="ROLE_USER" />
        </security:user-service>
    </security:authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>
```

and my EntryPoint:

```
public class EntryPoint extends BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint {

public void commence(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
        AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException,
        ServletException {
    HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;
    httpResponse.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_FORBIDDEN);
}
}
```

I tried a lot of things, like custom AuthenticationFailureHandler, or custom EntryPoint but nothing has worked so far.

Thanks

Edit:

My current solution only returns a 401 response with the basic tomcat templates and the browser asks for the user credentials.

When using the debugging mode, it seems that the commence() method of my custom entry point is never called, why is that?

Comment: Could you describe what your current solutions returns and what you would like it to return instead?

Comment: Instead of rolling your own (and basically rendering the `BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint` useless) use the `Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint` which always returns a 403 if authentication failed (instead of a 401 which is the default for basic authentication). Basically that should be all you need.

Comment: @M.Deinum I didn't think about this one, but using my custom Entry Point allows me to have more control on what the response is returning (I will also need to add a custom header in the future)

Comment: Your `commence` methods signature doesn't match the one as defined in the [`AuthenticationEntryPoint`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/AuthenticationEntryPoint.html) so it is just another method... However extending the `BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint` doesn't gain you anything imho as you are overriding its core method. You are probably better of by extending the `BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint`, add your headers and call `super.commence()` after that.

Comment: If you would place `@Override` on that method you probably get an exception...

Comment: Yes it was the problem! thanks!